Does it suffice to consider the limit only along the power paths?
$\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$For $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\R^n$, let
$$L(a):=\lim_{x\downarrow0}R_a(x)$$
if the limit exists, where
$$R_a(x):=\frac{x^a}{F(x)},$$
$x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\R^n$, $x\downarrow0$ means that $x_i\downarrow0$ for each $i\in[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, $x^a:=x_1^{a_1}\dotsm x_n^{a_n}$, $F(x):=\sum_{k\in S}x^k$, and $S$ is a finite nonempty subset of $\R^n$.

Is it then always true that $L(a)=0$ iff
$$l_p(a):=\lim_{t\downarrow0}R_a((t^{p_1},\dots,t^{p_n}))=0\text{ for all $p=(p_1,\dots,p_n)\in(0,\infty)^n$?}$$

This question is motivated by this previous one.

Yes. The following 3 conditions are equivalent:
(a) $L(a)=0$;
(b) $l_p(a)=0$ for all $p\in (0,+\infty)^n$;
(c) the polytope $P:={\rm conv} \, (S)$ contains a point $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ for which $a_i\geqslant b_i$ for all $i$ and $a_i>b_i$ for at least one index $i$.
Clearly (a) yields (b).
(c) yields (a).
Indeed, under condition (c) we have $F(x)\geqslant x^b$: if $b=\sum_{k\in S} t_k k$, where $t_k\geqslant 0$ and $\sum t_k=1$, then $x^b=\prod_k (x^{k})^{t_k}\leqslant \prod (F(x))^{t_k}=F(x)$. Thus, $x^a/F(x)\leqslant x^a/x^b=\prod x_i^{a_i-b_i}$ goes to 0 when $x_i\downarrow 0$.
(b) yields (c).
We prove that negation of (c) yields negation of (b). If (c) does not hold, then $P$ and the closed polyhedral cone $C:=a-\mathbb{R}_+^n$ are disjoint or have only one common point $a$. Then the polyhedral cones $a+\mathbb{R}_+\cdot (P-a)$ and $C$ can be strictly separated by a hyperplane passing through $a$ (it is important here that they are polyhedral). This hyperplane's equation is $\ell(v)=0$, where $\ell(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(a_i-v_i)$ for some coefficients $p_i>0$, and $\ell(k)\leqslant 0$ for all $k\in S$. Then $\prod t^{p_i k_i-p_ia_i}\leqslant 1$ for $0<t<1$, and $F(t^{p_1},\ldots,t^{p_n})\leqslant |S|t^{\sum p_i a_i}$. Thus (b) does not hold, as needed.

@QuýNhân this is certainly not true, you can add an element $c>a$ (coordinate wise) to $S$, and this does not affect $L(a)$

Thank you for your answer.

@FedorPetrov Your answer solved my problem, I'm grateful for that. Last question, do you have any references for this problem? I have been searching for it in Calculus books and texts but to no avail.

How do you get that $p_i>0$ for every $i$? I see $ \geq 0$ and $>0$ for some $i$.

@GiorgioMetafune if some $p_i=0$, our hyperplane does not strictly separate the cones

By strictly separate I mean $l(v)<l(w)$ for any $v,w$ belonging to differenti cones. But they can have a common point (and only one). How to prove that the above inequality holds for $v,w$ different from this common point. You say that this happens since they are polyehedral cones; I agree that this Is the point but I cannot fix It.

@GiorgioMetafune if you have two polyhedral cones $C_1,C_2$ with a vertex, say, in 0, which have unique common point 0, then $C=C_1-C_2$ is a convex polyhedral cone with vertex at 0 which does not contain a line though 0. Then there exists a support plane $H$ to $C$ at 0 with $H\cap C={0 }$. This plane gives the desired direction.
